# Assign comparison operator to variable?

Tags: python, operands

Is it possible to assign `<` to a variable, let's say `b` ?

For example:

`b = <` .

## Edit:

My plan is the following:

`a < b < c < d` .

I want add the "compares" to a permutation. I know that I can add `a b c d` to a permutation but I have to change the `<` too. Please believe me that this is important for my plan. I have to find all possibilities.

Comment: No. And I would strongly reconsider trying something like this.

Comment: No, not directly. If you were to tell us what you actually want to achieve instead of saying how you plan to solve a tiny little detail of it, we might actually be able to help you to find an elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: @ Varun Nayak Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assign operator to variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python)

Comment: Duplicate of [less-than-or-greater-than-comparison-as-a-variable-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349136/less-than-or-greater-than-comparison-as-a-variable-in-python)?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like so

```
b = '<'
c = '+'
```

When you want to use it, you have to use the `eval` function.

```
eval('5' + b + '10') # '5<10'
>>> True
eval('5' + c + '10') # '5+10'
>>> 15
```